# UITableview: Group style set in xib, still default style in simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a class which extends `UITableView`, and it has 4 sections. I need to add the `Grouped` style to it.

I opened the `xib` in Interface Builder and selected `Grouped` in styles. The UI in Interface Builder changed to `Grouped`, but when I ran the application it still shows the normal style.

How can I solve this?

I don't think I should have to supply any code here, because I used Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to try is a clean build, sometimes Xcode doesn't always get things right. The next thing to try is to add logging in your VC's viewDidLoad to make sure that the property is  set correctly.

Comment: I have been trying this for days and i have cleaned the project several times and also i have restarted my machine many times. :( what might had gone wrong ?

Comment: If that is the case, then you should put some logging code into your viewDidLoad and see what the style property on the tableView is returning. If it isn't returning UITableViewStyleGrouped (an int value of 1), then the table is not being deserialized from the nib properly.

Comment: If it is not being deserialized properly then you might try deleting the table view from the nib file and dragging a new one off of the Object Library.

Answer (score 1):

You said your class extends UITableViewController. This means the designated initializer is `initWithStyle:`, and you can only do that from code. So check where you did that, and initialize it with the grouped style, like `initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped`.

If your controller isn't extending UITableViewController, then you have it subclassing UIViewController and your tableView is set as an Outlet in your nib file, so make sure all the connections are ok. Also, clean your Project (Command+Shift+K, or click un Project -> Clean ) Xcode have some issues with these kind of things.

Comment: Do i have to type `initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped` in `ViewDidLoad` ?

Comment: You need to init it with `initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped` in the place you initialize your TableViewController instance.

Answer (score 1):

In Interface Builder, for the object that is your table view, make sure the class is correctly set to your subclass (in one of the panels on the right-hand side inspector) and not UITableViewController.

Answer (score -1):

```
   xxxiewController  *detailViewController = [[xxxViewController  alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```

if you're pushing tableview , set UITableViewStyleGrouped before view push.